# pushViewControllerAnimated pushes ViewController over whole screen

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to show a modal view controller that hovers over another viewcontroller. Now the problem is when I use pushViewControllerAnimated the view controller that gets pushed will be as big as the whole iphone screen. I just want it to be half size of the screen. 
How to adjust the size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by half size of the screen?
If you are interested in the Facebook-like side menu, have a look at:
https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck
or https://github.com/BenHall/ios_facebook_style_navigation

If you are interested in an alertview-like small modal view controller, you might:

- Consider using an alert view and adding some subviews
- Read http://devblog.bu.mp/easy-partial-screen-modals-on-ios if you really have to use an UIViewController for that, which is not recommended by Apple (http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am interested in presenting a modelviewcontroller that does not go over the whole screen